# How to check in pandas that column is bool-like (includes either True, False or NaN)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
  {
    'date':"20220701",
    'a':[1,2,np.NaN],
    'b':['a', 'b', 'c'], 
     'c':[True, False, np.NaN]
  }
)
```

columns `b` and `c` have therefore dtype object. I'd like to be able to efficiently distinguish columns, that could be boolean if they had no missing value.

Only solutions that came to my mind are:

1. check if the unique values in a column are in [true, false, NaN], but that would most likely be supper inefficient.
2. check where `(df.c.isnull() | (df.c == True) | (df.c == False)).all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it using assign

since the column is created via assign, its temporary, and not a part of df.
so, nothing is lost or added

```
#create a temp column by ffill NA value, and check temp column dtype
df.assign(temp=df['c'].ffill())['temp'].dtype
```

```
dtype('bool')
```

```
>> df.assign(temp=df['c'].ffill())['temp'].dtype == 'bool'
True
```

or

```
#list types of the column and the newly created one is of type bool
df.assign(temp=df['c'].ffill()).dtypes
```

```
date     object
a       float64
b        object
c        object
temp       bool
dtype: object
```

Comment: So when I fill all the missing values in bool-like column, the dtype automatically changes to bool?

Comment: correct. pandas assigns the dtype to bool, making it reliable measure

Comment: there are other ways, and you need to be cognizant that 1 and 0 values also get treated as true and false, without necessarily being in a  bool type column. so having Pandas decide it as bool is more reliable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `unique()` you could use something like `df.b[:10]` and compare those first 10 samples to assume if your data is boolean or not.

I think it can fail but it will be faster than `unique()` ...

Comment: Hello and thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately in my case this would fail frequently